# Combining two layers and removing their overlap using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, merge, overlapping-features, dissolve

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.0.

I have two polygon layers showing storm surge and I want them both to be combined to look like a smooth transition into each other. However, they have an overlap and it makes the appearance of them poor if they are combined using merge or union.

Would it be easier to convert them into rasters and perform a calculation through that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do you want to combine different overlapping values - mean, max, etc.? Also, what software are you using?

Comment: @phloem Mean for sure. I just want the values to be continuous across the region. But I also don't want there to be double the cell values where the overlap occurs. I am using ArcGIS 10.0

Comment: What do you mean that the appearance is poor when you use union? Is it the sharp breaks you don't like?

Comment: @phloem Yea when I used union there was a very sharp break between the features and it didn’t look natural.

Comment: In that case, I'd consider converting to raster, combining, then smoothing.

Answer (score -1):

you can accomplish it using this tool. 
http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/symmetrical-difference.htm